# Posting image to Facebook using SLRequest not working after Graph2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am having a very hard time figuring out what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the situation. I have an image and I am trying to auto share it to facebook. So as per facebook best practices, I first got the basic permissions, and then I am getting the publish_actions permissions. And when I am trying to post the picture, there is no error posted, but the NSURLResponse shows this.

`"Www-Authenticate" = "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"insufficient_scope\" \"(#200) Permissions error\"";`

Here is the code that I am using to share to facebook.

```
- (void) loginViaFacebookWithPublishCredentialsWithResponse:(BGResponseBlock)block
{
    if(!self.accountStore)
    {
        self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    }
    ACAccountType *facebookTypeAccount = [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookTypeAccount
                                               options:@{ACFacebookAppIdKey: FacebookAppIDKey,
                                                         ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_actions"],
                                                         ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceEveryone}
                                            completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if(granted)
         {
             NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:facebookTypeAccount];

             self.facebookAccount = accounts.lastObject;
             ACAccountCredential *fbCredential = [self.facebookAccount credential];
             if([fbCredential oauthToken])
             {
                 if(block)
                 {
                     block([fbCredential oauthToken],nil);
                 }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             if([error code] == 6)
             {
                 if(block)
                 {
                     block(nil,error);
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 NSLog(@"The original error while trying to log into facebook is %@", error);
                 NSError *accessDeniedError = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Access Denied" code:999 userInfo:nil];
                 if(block)
                 {
                     block(nil,accessDeniedError);
                 }
             }
         }
     }];
}

- (void) autoShareViaFacebook:(UIImage *)image withCaption:(NSString *)caption andResponseBlock:(void(^)(BOOL sharedSuccessfullyViaFB, NSError *error))block
{
    NSBlockOperation *uploadOperation = [[NSBlockOperation alloc] init];
    [uploadOperation addExecutionBlock:^
     {
         [self loginViaFacebookWithPublishCredentialsWithResponse:^(id responseObject, NSError *error)
          {
              if(responseObject && !error)
              {
                  NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message":caption};

                  SLRequest *request = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos"] parameters:parameters];
                  request.account = self.facebookAccount;

                  [request addMultipartData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) withName:@"source" type:@"multipart/form-data" filename:caption];
                  [request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                   {
                       //NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;

                       if (error)
                       {
                           // Post error data to NSLog
                           NSLog(@"SLRequest Error: %@", error);
                           if(block)
                           {
                               block(NO, error);
                           }
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           NSLog(@"Facebook autoshare successful!");
                           if(block)
                           {
                               block(YES,nil);
                           }
                       }
                   }];
              }
              else
              {
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                      if(block)
                      {
                          block(NO,error);
                      }
                  });
              }
          }];
     }];

    [[BGSocialInstance sharedInstance].operationQueue addOperation:uploadOperation];
}
```

When I print out the NSURLResponse, this is what I get.

```
po urlResponse
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x15e26430> { URL: https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos } { status code: 403, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-store";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 83;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Mon, 16 Jun 2014 17:52:11 GMT";
    Expires = "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    "Www-Authenticate" = "OAuth \"Facebook Platform\" \"insufficient_scope\" \"(#200) Permissions error\"";
    "X-FB-Debug" = "fH7p9jHKmUDEWpa36iKKp0T8zrAu3gyx46oqdzB1fmgEJMEhYuYDgJ33R7lDXfVXG5PGzrQCDXYUxtgh73sFOA==";
    "X-FB-Rev" = 1292193;
} }
```

And the response data when printed always gives this.

```
resposedata:{"error":{"message":"(#200) Permissions error","type":"OAuthException","code":200}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like, since Facebook moved to Graph 2.0, we need to request publish_actions permissions for the app that we created in developer.facebook.com. We need to submit a link that points to privacy policy, fill bunch of meta data and submit a build and FB will be reviewing it and giving access to the app, and everything should work with the code above.